# listen udp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

Tags: nginx, http3

```
sudo docker run -d -it -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp --name nginxx nginxx
4ae3a17df82316bd010a0899d91db78c6c64467e5c585a36e73fa3ae31975b1f
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginxx (2b5dc428167f20dfab55c573989562f9cc439ba0dfb94bae56085043dabf7613): Error starting userland proxy: listen udp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use.
```

How to solve this problem?

Kill all processes using port 443.

Comment: what is the output off `netstat -nlutp | grep 443`?

Comment: `udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                                -`

Answer (score 0):

Please kill all process that use port 443:

```
for i in $(lsof -i -P -n  | grep 443 | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $i ; done
```

then run your container again

```
sudo docker run -d -it -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp --name nginxx nginxx
```

Comment: not work........

Answer (score 0):

I am using wireguard. Wireguard uses udp, and the port of wireguard is 443. When I stopped wireguard, docker execution succeeded.

I wonder why wireguard didn't show up when I used `sudo netstat -nlutp | grep 443`.